# Progress bar in Bootstrap only displays percentage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

just a heads up I'm quite new to web development and in my case CSS3+HTML5+javascript

So I've got a section that is split into two columns. Left column is 60% and right is 30%. Left has paragraphs and the right needs to have 3 progress bars that contain my skills. This should be straight forward but unfortunately it seems to not work, only the percentage shows up. No actual bar appears.

```
<section id="about" class="main style1top dark fullscreen">
            <div class="content container 100%">

                <div class="column-left"> 
                    <h3 style="font-size:250%">About me</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <p>
                    Wow look at all my skills, I'm smart.
                    </p>        
                </div>

                <div class="column-right"> 
                    <h3 style="font-size:200%">Skills</h3>      
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
                            60%
                          </div>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <a href="#work" class="button style2 down anchored">Next</a>


        </section>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question/problem is.

Comment: The actual progress bar is not displayed. Only "60%" appears.

Comment: Seems OK here http://www.bootply.com/PiaeINmOMl

Comment: That's what I figured. I'm guessing the problem must be in style1top now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want a result like this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51j6prfk/)

To get that you need to include bootstrap

Placed in `<head></head>` tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

placed anywhere inside the `<body></body>` tags

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

furthermore i suggest reading [Get Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) part of bootstrap. This will help a lot in formatting your bootstrap applications.

Comment: Wow it was in fact the head tag. That's weird. I thought bootstrap came with all it's "stock" resources needed. Anyhow, time to learn, Thank you for understanding my lack of knowledge